# Kubuntu 17.04 upgrade to 17.10. Restart fails

Tags: upgrade

Upgraded and on restart got a blinking cursor on a blank screen. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and logged in - following message:

```
48.397370 Could not find key with description:[******]
48.397390 Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [same **** as above]
48.397414 Error Parsing options; rc = [-2]
```

My home drive is encrypted. Will a re-install from a live CD unblock this, or is there another way to unblock this?

Comment: I didn't even do a dist upgrade and I got this error...

Answer (score 0):

I took the bull by the horns and re-installed using a live CD and the problem has cleared. Thank you Melebius for the re-formatting!